# D3 exit() update() merge() issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to change the appearance of each red line by simply clicking on it. A click should change the label and also the line. In dependency of the current stroke type the line should either change to a clear "stroke" or a "stroke-dasharray". The same click also changes the label which switches between "dasharray" or "clear".

I thought I finally understand the D3 exit(). remove(). merge() pattern but it seems I am wrong. I do not want to change the amount of nodes or links this time. I am pointing to the attributes which I want to change dynamically.

As I understand the LinkLines getting "redrawn" as well as the "nodes" itself. But I want to update the current text and apperance only.

I am thankful for any hint.

```js
        var data = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
            }],
            "links": [{
                "source": 1,
                "target": 2,
                "text": "dashed"
            },
            {
                "source": 2,
                "target": 3,
                "text": "clear"
            },
            {
                "source": 3,
                "target": 1,
                "text": "clear"
            }
            ]
        };

        let nodes = data.nodes
        let links = data.links

        //Helper
        let nodeToDelete

        var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(250))


        linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
        nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

        restart()

        simulation
            .nodes(nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link").links(links)

        function tick() {
            linkLine.attr("d", function (d) {
                var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
                    dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            })

            node
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }


        function restart() {

            // Update linkLines
            linkLine = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(links, link => link.text) // ADD DATA KEY FOR LINK

            linkLine.exit().remove()

            const linkLineEnter = linkLine.enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "linkPath")
                .attr("class", function(d) {
                    if (d.text != "dashed") {
                        return "linkpath clearstroke"
                    } else if (d.text == "dashed") {
                        return "linkpath dasharray"
                    }
                })
                .attr("fill", "transparent")
                .attr("id", function (_, i) {
                    return "path" + i
                })
                .attr("cursor", "pointer")
                .on("click", function(_, d) {

                    let linkIndexOf = links.indexOf(d)

                    if (links[linkIndexOf].text == "clear") {
                        links[linkIndexOf].text = "dashed"
                    } else if (links[linkIndexOf].text == "dashed") {
                        links[linkIndexOf].text = "clear"
                    }

                    console.log(links)

                    restart()
                })

            linkLine = linkLineEnter.merge(linkLine)

            // Update linkText
            linkText = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel") // FIXED ClassName
                .data(links, link => link.text)  // ADD DATA KEY FOR TEXT

            linkText.exit().remove()

            const linkTextEnter = linkText.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("dy", -10)
                .attr("class", "linkLabel")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "linkLabel" + i })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("")

            linkTextEnter.append("textPath")
                .attr("xlink:href", function (_, i) {
                    return "#path" + i
                })
                .attr("startOffset", "50%")
                .attr("opacity", 0.75)
                .attr("cursor", "default")
                .attr("class", "linkText")
                .attr("color", "black")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.text
                })

            linkText = linkTextEnter.merge(linkText)

            // Update nodes
            node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
                .data(nodes, node => node.id) // ADD DATA KEY FOR NODE

            node.exit().remove()

            const nodesEnter = node.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragStarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragEnded)
                )

            nodesEnter.selectAll("circle")
                .data(d => [d])
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .style("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("r", 40)

            nodesEnter.append("text")
                .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", 20)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.id
                })

            node = nodesEnter.merge(node)

            // Update and restart the simulation.
            simulation
                .nodes(nodes);
            simulation
                .force("link")
                .links(links)
            simulation.restart().alpha(1)
        }
```

```css
    .clearstroke {
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .dasharray {
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        stroke-dasharray: 5;
    }
    
    .nodes {
        fill: whitesmoke;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
   

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, which should be refactored. However, addressing only your main complaint, there are two problems:

1. Keys (in the key function) should be **unique**. As you can see, `link.text` is not unique, but `link.source + link.target` is.
2. The class name is `linkPath`, not `linkpath`.

Here's your code with those changes:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
    }
  ],
  "links": [{
      "source": 1,
      "target": 2,
      "text": "dashed"
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 3,
      "text": "clear"
    },
    {
      "source": 3,
      "target": 1,
      "text": "clear"
    }
  ]
};

let nodes = data.nodes
let links = data.links

//Helper
let nodeToDelete

var width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function(event) {
    svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
  }))
  .append("g")

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id
  }).distance(250))


linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

restart()

simulation
  .nodes(nodes)
  .on("tick", tick)

simulation
  .force("link").links(links)

function tick() {
  linkLine.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
      dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  })

  node
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
}

function dragStarted(event, d) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(event, d) {
  d.fx = event.x;
  d.fy = event.y;
}

function dragEnded(event, d) {
  if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}


function restart() {

  // Update linkLines
  linkLine = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkPath")
    .data(links, link => link.index || link.source + "" + link.target) // ADD DATA KEY FOR LINK

  linkLine.exit().remove()

  const linkLineEnter = linkLine.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "linkPath")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      if (d.text != "dashed") {
        return "linkPath clearstroke"
      } else if (d.text == "dashed") {
        return "linkPath dasharray"
      }
    })
    .attr("fill", "transparent")
    .attr("id", function(_, i) {
      return "path" + i
    })
    .attr("cursor", "pointer");

  linkLine = linkLineEnter.merge(linkLine)

  linkLine.attr("class", function(d) {
    if (d.text != "dashed") {
      return "linkPath clearstroke"
    } else if (d.text == "dashed") {
      return "linkPath dasharray"
    }
  })

  linkLine.on("click", function(_, d) {

    let linkIndexOf = links.indexOf(d)

    if (links[linkIndexOf].text == "clear") {
      links[linkIndexOf].text = "dashed"
    } else if (links[linkIndexOf].text == "dashed") {
      links[linkIndexOf].text = "clear"
    }

    restart()
  })

  // Update linkText
  linkText = linksContainer.selectAll(".linkLabel") // FIXED ClassName
    .data(links, link => link.index || link.source + "" + link.target) // ADD DATA KEY FOR TEXT

  linkText.exit().remove()

  const linkTextEnter = linkText.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", -10)
    .attr("class", "linkLabel")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      return "linkLabel" + i
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("")

  linkTextEnter.append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(_, i) {
      return "#path" + i
    })
    .attr("startOffset", "50%")
    .attr("opacity", 0.75)
    .attr("cursor", "default")
    .attr("class", "linkText")
    .attr("color", "black")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text
    })

  linkText = linkTextEnter.merge(linkText)

  linkText.select("textPath")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text
    })

  // Update nodes
  node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(nodes, node => node.id) // ADD DATA KEY FOR NODE

  node.exit().remove()

  const nodesEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragStarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragEnded)
    )

  nodesEnter.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => [d])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("r", 40)

  nodesEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 20)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id
    })

  node = nodesEnter.merge(node)

  // Update and restart the simulation.
  simulation
    .nodes(nodes);
  simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(links)
  simulation.restart().alpha(1)
}
```

```css
.clearstroke {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.dasharray {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5;
}

.nodes {
  fill: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
  <!-- D3 -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo, those typo mistakes.. Is there any particular reason why the first link with index 0 does not change to "clear" if clicked? It works with all other links

Comment: @ICoded That's because you're not changing the update selection, check the snippet again. I also changed the key function for concatenating strings (your source and targets are numbers).